# Oracle DB: delete all the contents

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have oracle DB it is for testing purpose, I have not added any tables. I just want clear all the files like control, redo, archive, date. Ultimately I want fresh db. I know it can done by delete the db and recreate.

I have searched in the internet could not find any relevant information.

Update:
The reason for this requirement is, some of the above mentioned files are corrupted.

Please advice,

Thanks,

Comment: If you need it for learning you can use `DROP DATABASE` statement. Then use tool dbca to create database creation scripts. And then execute them one-by-one. You never will have an empty database. Oracle itself stores a lot of metadata in there.

Answer (score 3):

> Ultimately I want fresh db

Then do the following:

- Open **DBCA**
- Select the operation "**Delete Database**", put the required credentials when asked.
- After completion of step 2, go back to first step.
- Select the operation "**Create Database**"